# Can you create a default JButton which sets default properties like bounds, border style etc for all buttons that I create later?

Tags: java

I am trying to create a lot of buttons which the number of buttons is set by the user so I dont know how to take the input of the user and create that much variables as the input. And because of that java outputs an error because there is no size the button isnt shown, because the button isnt saved into a variable.

To simplify it: If its possible I am trying to create a default button and use its size and styling for other buttons as well, if I need to change something for a specific button I will just manually add new properties.

If you know a better solution I would gladly hear it and try it.

```
ArrayList<JButton> arrListOfTask = new ArrayList<>();
arrListOfTask.add(new JButton(task));
// Task is just a String
```

If I put properties like directly into the *new JButton* then the button wont be added into the *ArrayList*. For example:

```
ArrListOfTask.add(new JButton(task).setBounds(x-pos, y-pos, width, height));
// This doesn't work
```

If I didn't explain properly please just ask for more explanation and I will do my best to explain.

Comment: What about creating a helper method which creates the button and changes the properties?

Comment: @Progman I will try it and notify if I could do something. Thanks :)

Comment: I hope you're not planning on using a [null layout](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/114-avoid-null-layouts-in-swing)?

Comment: Hmm. Plan One: `setLayout(null)` Plan Two: `setLayout(new BoxLayout()` So far, so even, but if you think pursuing Plan One is going to *save* you coding, you're *very* much mistaken

Comment: I only use `setLayout(null)` when I have too much object to put into a class that's why I use it. Cuz it looks better and you can do much more with it. And I don't know why people scream so much about it when its mentioned like its not like it makes your life coding harder. For me its just like "recursion" its harder to formulate it but its much easier to be done once its formulated. So thank you, but based on other people opinions `setLayout(null)` makes my code appear more readable and it saves my time. Again thanks for your concern, but @Progman helped me to get my answer.